# Datagridview to CSV not saving correctly

Tags: c#, csv, format

I have the below code to export DataGridView data to a CSV file. This CSV file is then used to import data into another system.

However, the system does not like the file when we import it. But if we open the CSV file click SAVE and close, the system accepts it.

When we create the CSV manually we just save the file as 'CSV (Comma delimited)'. Which the system accepts fine.

I have tried a few different types of ENCODING which you can see from the comments out lines.

```
private void SaveToCSV(DataGridView DGV)
        {
            string filename = "";
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "CSV (*.csv)|*.csv";
            sfd.FileName = "DataConversion.csv";
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (File.Exists(filename))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        File.Delete(filename);
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("It wasn't possible to write the data to the disk." + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                //Column Names = ""
                string columnNames = "PER_REF_NO,OBJECT,POST_NO,EFFECTIVE_DATE,REP_OBJECT,REP_POST_NO";
                //Count rows in DataGridView + 1
                string[] output = new string[DGV.RowCount + 1];
                output[0] += columnNames;
                int[] cols = new int[] { 0, 1, 11, 18, 21, 22 };

                for (int i = 1; (i - 1) < DGV.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    foreach (int col in cols)
                    {
                        if (col == 1 || col == 21)
                        {
                            output[i] += "POSITION" + ",";
                        }
                        else if (col == 18)
                        {
                            string formatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DGV.Rows[i - 1].Cells[col].Value).ToString("yyyMMdd");
                            output[i] += formatedDate + ",";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            output[i] += DGV.Rows[i - 1].Cells[col].Value?.ToString() + ",";
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(sfd.FileName, output, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
                //System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(sfd.FileName, output, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252"));
                //System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(sfd.FileName, output, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

                //CLEAR DGV AFTER EXPORT
                DGV.Rows.Clear();
                DGV.Refresh();
                MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully");
            }
        }
```

Comment: You say when you open the file and save it again it then starts working. What are you opening the file in as most decent text editors try and keep the source formatting and encoding if possible?

You could also use Notepad++ to see if there are non-printable bytes messing up the format being saved in the file somewhere by going to `View > Show Symbols > Show All Characters`.

Most of my formatting issues come down to byte order marks, the wrong line endings, or needing a newline at the end of the file, all of which can be found this way.

Comment: I am opening the file in MS Excel. Then clicking save and it works.

Comment: Using you suggestion in Notepad++ i think i have found the problem. It is showing the data as e.g. "Data,data,data," I do not think the comma should be after the final data. So when I open it in Excel it is probably automatically correcting this, and when i save the file is now fine. But if i do not open in Excel the file is incorrect

Comment: In notepad++ if you do a find and replace, select extended mode, and replace ",\n" with "\n" then save the file. This will remove trailing commas before the end of a line. If this now works the  those trailing commas are your problem and you need to fix that in your software.